# Create an apartment model with four rooms with three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I want to create an apartment model with four rooms.

[image: The ideal plan]

For that I will create four transparent cubes representing the pieces.
I created one, but I have trouble adding the other three pieces.

[image: Room]

I'm using the three.js framework.

```
// geometry
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 20, 10, 20 );

    // material
    var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
        color: 0xffffff, 
        transparent: false,
        side: THREE.BackSide
    } );

    // mesh
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material2 );
    scene.add( mesh );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 20, 10, 20 );
// material
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff, 
    transparent: false,
    side: THREE.BackSide
} );

// mesh
for(var y=0;y<1;y++)
for(var x=0;x<1;x++){
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.set(x*20,0,y*20);
    scene.add( mesh );
}
```

Also check out this project:

http://furnishup.github.io/blueprint3d/example/

Comment: Thank you @manthrax, how can I iterate with the objects in the room ? (add tooltips for exemple ?)